# TYPO3 how to clear a .getJSON(ajaxUrl) request?

Tags: ajax, typo3, getjson

Even though I'm using different ajaxUrl's. Like `ajax01Url`, `ajax02Url`, *etc*. Each one of them with its own typeNum. I keep getting the same array content in `function(data)`.

Any suggestions how to clean this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It was my own fault, I had a typo on the action name :)

I was calling the two different uri.action with the same name. Even though they have different pageType.